# Book's for potential theory: single and double layer potential

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

Does anyone know recommend me some book about the theory of the potential, especially that concerning the layer potential. Besides the theoretical part in the higher dimension, if there are concrete examples as when $n=3$ is better!

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

*Foundation of Potential Theory* by O.D. Kellogg.

**Added**: Lester Helms' *Potential Theory* is more  modern than Kellogg, but (if memory serves) Kellogg has more worked-out calculations. For the two-dimensional case it's hard to do better than *Potential theory in the complex plane* by T. Ransford. The two-volume *Subharmonic Functions* by W.K. Hayman is excellent and comprehensive. And don't forget *Classical potential theory* by D. Armitage and S. Gardiner, which is probably the most up to date of the books mentioned.

Comment: You know something more recent?

Comment: But none of them follows specifically the "sub-theory" of single and double layer potential. In this context it should also include the theory of integral operators, and this from a theoretical point of view.